# Themes' screenshots not visible after 8.6.1 update

Tags: theming

Once I have updated the multisite (using composer), all the screenshots images just stopped showing.

If I try to access the image directly (using browser) the message is like that:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /themes/contrib/bootstrap/screenshot.png on this server.
```

But the sites seem to work ok. It's just an admin UI problem.

Comment: While updating your site (how exactly did you do this, with what command, and what got updated, and what's your project structure?) the `.htaccess` file probably got reset. Check this file and fix it, most likely it's the `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: _It's just an admin UI problem_ That's unlikely; the error message most likely comes from your web server, not Drupal

Comment: Uncommented the `RewriteBase /`line but it changed nothing. It was commented out on the other hosting as well. Looked back at old hosting the same issue on the former/other platform.

Comment: Have also found that the icon of the themes admin menu (3rd from left in my case) vanished from UI as well... very strange.

Comment: Had found absolutely unbelievable solution.. Accessing the site using SSL/https solves the problem. What more the Devel module "Appearance" menu item icon is back as well. The issue is recoverable no SSL access has a fault while SSL is ok.